# Python 3 Logical Operators: Newbie query

Tags: python

Regarding Logical Operators in python. Can someone please explain: Why ('a' > 'b')= False in python.

Comment: What would you expect it to return? Please read [ask].

Comment: @j1-lee, careful with the word "dictionary" :-). Python has [a data structure with that name](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)...

Comment: This is called Lexigraphical ordering. The concept is to define an ordered relationship between things. In this case, strings are ordered by the relationship of their characters.

Comment: `'a' > 'b'` returns false because.... _it's false_.  `'a'` comes _before_ `'b'`, not after.

Comment: See [Python String Comparison](https://www.journaldev.com/23511/python-string-comparison).

Comment: Consider `1` and `2`. Is `1 > 2` true or false?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this isn't a tutorial service. If something doesn't make sense to you, we can't just explain it to you in a vacuum, because we have no idea why you don't understand it already. To ask a meaningful question, you should have a specific idea about *what should happen instead, and why* (i.e., with your own reasoning behind it). Otherwise, the assistance you need comes from *following a tutorial from the beginning*, or possibly from trying an actual discussion forum like Reddit or Quora.

Comment: If "because the designers said so" is a good enough answer to "why" for you, then the real question is "*what is the rule* that Python is using to decide this?", and the way you answer a question like that is to *read the documentation*. The official Python website includes full documentation with a built-in tutorial and as much detail as you could ever ask for.

Answer (score 3):

People comment that it's because *'a' comes before 'b'*, which is true. I would assume that this order is defined in the [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/).

In the example of `'a' > 'b'` the ASCII value of 'a' is 97 whereas 'b' is 98 (you can get those values in python using the `ord` function). So, is `97 > 98`? It's not.

Comment: "I would assume that this order is defined in the ASCII table." Strictly speaking, it is defined by the Unicode standard, which (wayyyyyy back in 1991) assigned the first 128 code points to the corresponding ASCII values for the sake of backwards compatibility.